# Is there a specific word or term for the two dots (":") between hours and minutes?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Is there a specific word or term for the two dots in this "14:23"?

Edit. I know it's a colon. :-) I mean specifically related to date and time display.

Comment: It's a colon; this is one of its uses.

Comment: It's a [colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [colon](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29). The typographic symbol -
:

Its usage in denoting time is not universal, however.  [Many countries use a period (full stop) in its place. (14.23 for 2:23 PM).](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe)

To my knowledge there is not a special term to designate a colon separating hours:minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is a [colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29). In your example, it might also be called a [seperator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separator) or a [delimiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)